# Sync data from local SQL Server to MySQL Server on Internet (live server)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, web-services

I have upload local server data to live server mean i work offline after work done and testing the data on localhost. Sync data from local SQL Server to MySQL Server on Internet (live server). I wanna save time. I found some article about web services may it help full . I am a php new developer and to do this task in php. any way to do this any suggestion and method.

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're asking.  If you can give some code that you have so far and tell us why the code doesn't meet your requirements then we'll be in a better position to help you.  Without these details then we can't help :(

Comment: I'm trying to work out what the question is. Are you asking how you can run PHP offline/Locally?

Comment: @NewToJS... I think that you might have cracked it there.  Have you thought about becoming a translator?

Comment: @Coulton I had to read this a few times but most *new* to php attempt to run php locally and fail. It's a common mistake. But... If this is the question- I use Wampserver for server-side testing http://www.wampserver.com/en/ **OR** you can use https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: Sorry All of you guys i try to explain it again.

Answer (score 0):

I use WAMP server to work with PHP/MySQL offline.  You just install it and then you can plonk your PHP files in there and run it from `http://localhost`.

If you want to run you code locally and point it to your live server this is entirely possible.  You just need to make sure that you have access to the relative ports that your database runs on etc.

See http://wampserver.com

Comment: mean Sync data from local SQL Server to MySQL Server on Internet. which post relative item enter on localhost